# два конструктора с одинаковой шапкой в теле

Tags: c++, конструктор

как грамотно в плюсах организовать 2 разных конструктора имеющих одинаковый общий код в начале, а остальной код "свой"

```
  TextFrameBase(int size,int a , int b,int c) {
/*общий код*/
/*какой-то свой код для этого конструктора 1*/
}
  TextFrameBase(int size) {
/*общий код*/
/*какой-то свой код для этого конструктора 2*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как всегда есть три базовых способа.

- вынести общий код в отдельную функцию. Тут все очевидно.
- использовать [делегирующий конструктор](https://habr.com/ru/post/157315/).

  ```
    class TextFrameBase {
    public:
      TextFrameBase(int size, int c) {/*общий код*/}
      TextFrameBase(int size,int a , int b,int c) : TextFrameBase(size, c) {
        /*какой-то свой код для этого конструктора 1*/
      }
      TextFrameBase(int size) : TextFrameBase(size, 1) {
        /*какой-то свой код для этого конструктора 2*/
      }
   }
  ```
- вынести общий код в код класса предка/[шаблона crtp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)
- ну и как всегда, если стандартные способы не помогают, то можно использовать макросы. Главное не порезаться.

Comment: способ №2 с делегирующим констром ничо такой. пойдет, спасибо )

Comment: он правда доступен только с 11 плюсов, но я думаю, в 2021 году об этом уже упоминать нужно аккуратно. Главное не вызывать один конструктор в коде другого конструктора просто так. И вспомнился ещё метод через placement ctor + this, но для очень древних компиляторов.